# DataRow GetHashCode() method value won't change after editing row

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, hashcode

I have a Datatable, and I want to compare the hashcodes of each row before and after I make edits to the rows of the datatable
This is how I get HashCode, storing it in the dictionary along with a key, and returning it

```
        Dictionary<string, int> mydict1= new Dictionary<string, int>();

        foreach (DataRow row in DataTable.Rows)
        {
            mydict.Add(row["Name"].ToString(), row.GetHashCode());
        }

        return mydict1;
```

After editing the values in the rows of datatable I call the same function again and get all the hash code values for rows and store it in mydict2.
When I compare mydict1 and mydict2 they are exactly same, even thought I have done edits to the rows. How can I capture the edits? Or how can I get the hashcode of values in a row originally? Perhaps I am not getting the hashcode correctly, please help.

Comment: You shouldn't use the hashes provided by `Object.GetHashCode()` to compare objects in this manner. From MSDN "Do not test for equality of hash codes to determine whether two objects are equal. (Unequal objects can have identical hash codes.) To test for equality, call the ReferenceEquals or Equals method."

Comment: *"I want to compare the hashcodes of each row before and after I make edits to the rows of the datatable"* Why do you want to do this? This sounds like a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) Tell us what problem you have that you think comparing hash codes is the solution and we will tell you the correct way to solve that problem.

Comment: If you are trying to determine which rows have been modified, you could use [`DataRow.RowState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.rowstate.aspx) instead.

Comment: I want to find out wether or not the rows been modified, and the ones that have, save to database. Do you know how can I get the checksum of the row? Datarow.Rowstate won't be helpful in my case.

Comment: "Datarow.Rowstate won't be helpful in my case"  Why not?

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming that you aren't using a custom `DataRow` class and you are expecting `GetHashcode` to return some sort of "checksum" value based on the contents of the `DataRow`.

That's not what `GetHashCode` does, nor *should it*.  Hash codes are for *storing items in a `Dictionary`* or other hash-based collection.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx):

> A hash code is a numeric value that is used to insert and identify an object in a hash-based collection such as the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` class, the `Hashtable` class, or a type derived from the `DictionaryBase` class.

The default behavior of `GetHashCode` returns equal hash codes for equal *instances* of an object, regardless of any underlying values within that object, which is why you're getting the same value before an after the change.

Please read the rest of the documentation linked above to see other appropriate (and inappropriate) uses of hash codes.

If you want to *reliably* see if a row has been modified, you'll have to **keep a copy of the previous values and compare them column-by-column**.  Any hashing algorithm *could* result in the same checksum for rows with different column values.

You *could* use [`DataRowComparer.GetHashCode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb908065%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but be aware that it's not 100% guaranteed to indicate whether a row has changed or not.

Comment: Oh I see. That is exactly what I wanted to get - a checksum of the datarow. I am thinking to concatenate the values of datarow in single string then convert it to binary, or something like that, in order to get the checksum, do you have any ideas how to get the checksum of the raw in better way?

Comment: You could use something like [`Sha1.ComputeHash()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha1.computehash(v=vs.110).aspx), but that requires you to convert each column value to some sort of byte array.

Answer (score 1):

I used a method to verify if a incoming datarow from a CSV has changed.  Originally I used the GetHAshCode() just to discover that it wasn't going to work as I thought.

Here's what I did....

I created a SHA1 hash method as follows:

```
    static string Hash(string input)
    {
        using (SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed())
        {
            var hash = sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
            var sb = new StringBuilder(hash.Length * 2);

            foreach (byte b in hash)
            {
                // can be "x2" if you want lowercase
                sb.Append(b.ToString("X2"));
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
```

To get the datarow into a string value I did the following:

```
    string _szImportRecordHash = Hash(String.Join(",", drRow.ItemArray) );
```

The above code has a String.Join which takes the itemArray and returns a comma delimited string back.

I then stored this value in the DB and compared the single hash to verify the row has changed.  If it didn't match then I processed changes into the DB on individual items.

This has been working beautifully for me.